Golang JSON to struct results in cannot unmarshal
I am trying to unmarshal this API response to a Golang struct.
{
    "0": {
        "article_id": 1,
        "article_inwebshop": 0,
        "article_number": 1111111,
        "article_season": 0,
        "sizeruler": -3,
        "article_freefield2": null,
        "article_manufacturer": null,
        "article_artfabr": null,
        "article_freefield1": "name here",
        "article_color": null,
        "article_subgroup": "name here",
        "article_group": "name here",
        "article_price_web": "",
        "article_additional_info": "",
        "article_description": "name here",
        "article_creation_date": "2016-09-30",
        "article_basepurprice": "0.00",
        "article_baseprice": "0.00",
        "article_outlet": 0,
        "article_discount": "",
        "article_memo": "name here",
        "article_supplier": null,
        "article_price_web_discount": "",
        "article_homepage": 0,
        "article_weight": "1.60",
        "article_run_out": 0,
        "article_metakeywords": "name here",
        "article_metadescription": "name here",
        "article_metatitle": "name here",
        "article_price_wholesale": "0.00",
        "article_subsubgroup": "name here",
        "salesunit": 1,
        "article_deposit": "0.00",
        "deliverytime": null,
        "article_taxrate": "21.00",
        "article_group_extra": [],
        "article_is_composed": "false",
        "fields": {
            "aantal_flessen": "",
            "alcoholpercentage": "40%",
            "beschikbaarheid": "",
            "bottelaar": "name here",
            "distillery_merk": "name here",
            "druivensoort": "",
            "gebotteld": "",
            "gedistilleerd": "",
            "inhoudsmaat": "1 liter",
            "land": "",
            "leeftijd": "no-age-statement",
            "oogstjaar": "",
            "regio": "name here",
            "serie": "",
            "vatnummer": "",
            "vattype": "name here",
            "verpakking": "",
            "wijnhuis_merk": "",
            "article_memo_en": "",
            "datum_nieuw_binnen": "",
            "doos_prijs": "",
            "add_informatie": "",
            "test": "",
            "maximum_aantal_per_klant": ""
        },
        "virtual_articles": [],
        "virtual_article_parents": [],
        "images": [
            {
                "image_description": "Shan_Classic",
                "image_file": "Shan_Classic.jpg",
                "image_order": 1,
                "image_link": "Shan_Classic.jpg",
                "image_checksum": "234234234"
            },
            {
                "image_description": "Anto_Classic",
                "image_file": "Anto_Classic.jpg",
                "image_order": 2,
                "image_link": "Anto_Classic.jpg",
                "image_checksum": "234234234"
            }
        ],
        "sizes": [
            {
                "position": 1,
                "description": null,
                "stock": 0,
                "salepricedelta": "0.00",
                "purpricedelta": "0.00"
            }
        ],
        "barcodes": [
            {
                "position": 1,
                "barcode": "123123123"
            },
            {
                "position": 1,
                "barcode": "123123123"
            }
        ],
        "article_crossell": [],
        "article_upsell": [],
        "article_composed": [],
        "article_actions": []
    },
    "next_page": 2
}

I tried various things, but I am unable to get it working. My latest code is:
var items map[string]types.Synchronize
err = json.Unmarshal(body, &items)
if err != nil {
  fmt.Println(err)
  return
}

But this results in the following error:

json: cannot unmarshal number into Go value of type types.Synchronize

Can anyone please explain to me what I am doing wrong? I tried various ways of unmarshalling this thing, but without any luck so far.
This is my Synchronize struct:
type Synchronize struct {
    ArticleId                 int64           `json:"article_id"`
    ArticleInWebshop          int64           `json:"article_inwebshop"`
    ArticleNumber             int64           `json:"article_number"`
    ArticleSeason             int64           `json:"article_season"`
    ArticleManufacturer       string          `json:"article_manufacturer"`
    ArticleGroup              string          `json:"article_group"`
    ArticleSubgroup           string          `json:"article_subgroup"`
    ArticleSubSubGroup        string          `json:"article_subsubgroup"`
    ArticleDescription        string          `json:"article_description"`
    ArticleAdditionalInfo     string          `json:"article_additional_info"`
    ArticleBasePrice          string          `json:"article_baseprice"`
    ArticleOutlet             int64           `json:"article_outlet"`
    ArticleDiscount           string          `json:"article_discount"`
    ArticleMemo               string          `json:"article_memo"`
    ArticleSupplier           string          `json:"article_supplier"`
    ArticleWeight             string          `json:"article_weight"`
    ArticleVolume             string          `json:"inhoudsmaat"`
    ArticleMetaTitle          string          `json:"article_metatitle"`
    ArticleMetaKeywords       string          `json:"article_metakeywords"`
    ArticleMetaDescription    string          `json:"article_metadescription"`
    ArticleTaxRate            string          `json:"article_taxrate"`
    ArticleSalesUnit          int64           `json:"salesunit"`
    ArticleAlcoholPercentage  string          `json:"alcoholpercentage"`
    ArticleBottler            string          `json:"bottelaar"`
    ArticleDistillery         string          `json:"distillery_merk"`
    ArticleCountry            string          `json:"land"`
    ArticleHarvestYear        string          `json:"oogstjaar"`
    ArticleRegion             string          `json:"regio"`
    ArticleBarrelType         string          `json:"vattype"`
    ArticleAddInformation     string          `json:"add_informatie"`
    ArticleBarcodes           string          `json:"ArticleBarcodes"`
    ArticleGrapeDetails       string          `json:"druivensoort"`
    ArticleMaximumPerCustomer string          `json:"maximum_aantal_per_klant"`
    ArticleImages             []ArticleImages `json:"images"`
}

type ArticleImages struct {
    ArticleImageDescription string `json:"image_description"`
    ArticleImageFile        string `json:"image_file"`
    ArticleImageOrder       int64  `json:"image_order"`
    ArticleImageLink        string `json:"image_link"`
    ArticleImageChecksum    string `json:"image_checksum"`
}

It is important to notice, that the API response gives an array of textual numbers back, but also a "next_page" which is very important, and which I need.
So basically this is what the API response gives me:
{
  "0": {},
  "1": {},
  "2": {},
  "next_page": 2,
}

I have an online version available here: https://go.dev/play/p/EeMxWbolO1r
I don't know how to make the "text" to JSON so if you check the code, please adjust that. But the original response is there to work with.
EDIT:
Got it working with the tips to make it an interface{}.
But when I loop over the array now, it is broken.
Value one starts with "map[article_actions:[]" as it should.
But value two starts with "Nose: Subdued, citric fruitiness;" which is probably part of the description.
So something is wrong here.

If you have any error, please update your question with the error. And it will be helpful to have the types.Synchronize struct.

The error is in my post. it is: json: cannot unmarshal number into Go value of type types.Synchronize. I will add my struct to the post in a minute!

Oh, I think that your next_page is the cause of the error. So if you are sure about the numbers present in the response, you can create a struct that represent this object and use this instead of a map. If this is not the case, you should use {}interface instead of types.Synchronize and then have another loop where you create your actual map and cast all the object, and save the next_page value.

You were right, sharp eye! But when I print my struct, it is all messed up. Seems like data is not correctly. I will make an online example, that is easier ;)

The problem in your code is due to the "next_page" field being a number, and therefore it will fail on Unmarshaling, what you can do is having the object marshaled into map[string]interface{} and handle the next_page attributes seperately.

You are right, it was due to the "next_page" field. But, when I loop through the results, the results look off. For example it shows, 1, 3, 5, 7 and later on "2" but with empty results. Others start with the "description" while others display an object (as it should).
So something is still wrong I recon.
